# Git ignore embedded repositories

Tags: git, nested, repository, gitignore

I have an all-encompassing repository to track my notes. But next to the notes, there are often git repositories that I don't want to track.

This is how my gitignore is setup:

```sh
*.*
!*.kts
!*.org
!*.md
!*.txt
!*.sc
```

And it works really well, so much so that I can simply do `git add .`, except for the aforementioned case of nested repositories. Currently, I have to manually add them to the gitignore - if I don't, this happens:

```
❯ g add 1-projects
warning: adding embedded git repository: 1-projects/mixxx/mixxx-manual
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> 1-projects/mixxx/mixxx-manual
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached 1-projects/mixxx/mixxx-manual
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
warning: adding embedded git repository: 1-projects/mixxx/mixxx
warning: adding embedded git repository: 1-projects/mixxx/website
```

Which is what I would like to avoid. Is there some way to configure git or my gitignore to always simply ignore embedded repositories?

Comment: There does not seem to be. The [gitsubmodules documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) mentions `submodule.active` and shows a way to specifically de-activate submodules by pathspec, but this does not seem to affect what you're doing.

Comment: yep, I tried `submodule.active=false` or an exclude rule with a star, all to no avail. I guess I gotta continue with custom ignore specs and maybe submit a feature request.

Comment: A command-line flag to `git add` could also work, but there's nothing either :/ maybe I can create a script-workaround using the error message git show when adding a submodule.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

git config submodule..active false

Comment: can you separate the commands from other text like so `git config` and elaborate more on the issue

Comment: Hey @asdasf! Sorry, this doesn't seem to work. Please check it again and ensure [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) :)